Show BitLocker-encrypted drive labels in File Explorer
I have several BitLocker-encrypted external drives and partitions.
The drive letters are obviously mutable and not tied to any drive or partition, so the only way to determine which password belongs to which drive or partition I could think of is through drive labels which are tied to drives and partitions.
However, File Explorer doesn't show the drive label until the drive is unlocked...
which I can't do reliably until I know the label, creating a vicious cycle.
How do Microsoft expect the user to go about determining which password belongs to which drive or partition?
I guess one way would be to use the same password for every drive, but that just strikes me as the (very) wrong way to go.

If your question actually is, "How do Microsoft expect the user to go about determining which password belongs to which drive or partition?", that isn't something we can answer. There are ways to make a specific removable drive always have the same drive letter.  Do you often attach multiple BitLocker protected drives all at once?

An alternative would be to use encryption on a folder for each drive (if BitLocker cannot do so, VeraCrypt or alternative could). The drive (root) would mount automatically, but access to the folder would require password -- and the folder can be named. Caveat: Someone with access to the drive could delete the folder, though not read or modify.

@Ramhound usually not at once, no. Why isn't it something you can answer? Sounds pretty straightforward. E.g. "How do Microsoft expect the user to list files in a directory?" - File Explorer, Get-ChildItem, dir. It just sounds like a pretty big design flaw. An encrypted partition has to have a password, yet there is no way to identify which password belongs to which partition without hacks like forcing a drive letter.

@gargoylebident - We cannot explain Microsoft’s intentions or executions. If you are mounting and unlocking individual drives you should be able to identify the drive and use the password. I recommend a password manager.  BitLocker cannot encrypt individual folders, that’s EFS, which is not full disk encryption.

@Ramhound I think you misunderstood my question. I am not asking to explain Microsoft's intentions or executions. I am asking how I, a Windows user, am expected to know which password belongs to which drive. I am using a password manager. That is in fact precisely why I am asking this question. To explain in a different way, what is supposed to be the login part of the password manager entry? As is, I only know the password. Imagine a password manager with only passwords. If you have multiple accounts on the same site, how will you distinguish which password belongs to which account?

@Ramhound and I'll repeat, I'm using multiple partitions. How am I expected to distinguish them without knowing the label?

Wait? You have individual encrypted partitions instead of encrypting the disk? I must have not understood what you meant by "multiple disks and partitions". You say you are not asking for us to explain Microsoft expectations, but you literally asked, "How do Microsoft expect the user". I would agree; If you want to partition a single disk and use BitLocker on each individual partition instead of the entire disk.  You will want to use virtual HDD files and mount (and encrypt) those instead.

@Ramhound unsure if you're trying to play a semantic game, but yes, I asked that and no, I didn't say I'm not asking that. Yes, the partitions are encrypted. That is stated in the literal first sentence of my question. Additionally, why would I mention partitions five times in my question, if it weren't relevant to the question? In any case, I've found an answer to my question that doesn't involve workarounds like converting all my partitions to something else entirely and will post it in a bit.

@gargoylebident - I personally don’t normally encrypt individual partitions just entire disks with BitLocker.
